# Webpage Text gets pixelated on webview

Tags: android, html, css, webview

I have this following page

Now on my text and other contents, my text and images are pixelated. on bigger devices.

[image: nexus s and galaxy nexus]

as you can see in the image the text on nexus s looks great. but on galaxy nexus its pixelated.

this is  my meta tag

```
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
```

when I add `target-densitydpi=device-dpi` everything becomes smaller and my media queries doesn't work. it shows how the website viewed in a desktop version.

How can i make it nice on the galaxy nexus?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
[http://www.icondeposit.com/blog:how-to-properly-smooth-font-using-css3](http://www.icondeposit.com/blog%3ahow-to-properly-smooth-font-using-css3)

```
html, html a {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
}
```